# how to select a program as an "open with" option on mac osx

Tags: macos

I'm using mac osx 10.7.5 and I want to be able to right click a file and chose open with... and have the icon appear in that menu, without having to select "other" and go to my application folder to chose the program. I do not want this program to be the default though (the default should stay as it is). How do I add the program to this context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add entries to the CFBundleDocumentTypes array in the Info.plist, but it would get overridden by updates. If the application is signed, it also breaks the code signature, and some applications like TextEdit and Chess will crash on launch.

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
    <array>
        <string>txt</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

To register the changes, run `/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -f /Applications/SomeApp.app/` and `killall Finder`.

Comment: No need to run `lsregister` manually, just touch the application bundle (`touch /Applications/SomeApp.app`), then deselect and reselect the application in the Finder. The updated mod date will force the Finder to re-examine the Info.plist and re-register the app automatically.

Comment: I ended up solving it with your method, NSGod